# Explain why this DataRow is not changed

Tags: .net, vb.net, reference, datarow, object-reference

Can anyone explain exactly why Method 1 in the following code does not alter the DataTable where the other 2 methods do?

It's obviously some kind of referencing issue, but why exactly?

[CODE AT IDEONE HERE](http://ideone.com/AMIFV)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data

Public Class Test

        Public Shared Sub Main()
                'Build Table
                Dim dt as New DataTable
                dt.Columns.Add("ID",GetType(String))
                dt.Columns.Add("Name",GetType(String))

                'Populate Table
                Dim dr as DataRow
                dr = dt.NewRow()
                dr("ID")="Man" : dr("Name") = "mike" : dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                dr = dt.NewRow()
                dr("ID")="Man" : dr("Name") = "ian" : dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                dr = dt.NewRow()
                dr("ID")="Man" : dr("Name") = "rob" : dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                dr = dt.NewRow()
                dr("ID")="Woman" : dr("Name") = "ann" : dt.Rows.Add(dr)
                dr = dt.NewRow()
                dr("ID")="Woman" : dr("Name") = "sam" : dt.Rows.Add(dr)

                output(dt)      'Output Table

                Dim drFilters() as DataRow = dt.Select("ID='Man'")      'Select all Man

                'Method 1 does not change dt
                'dr = dt.NewRow()
                'dr("ID")="cowman" : dr("Name")="bugle"
                'drFilters(1)=dr

                'Method 2 does change dt
                dr = drFilters(1)
                dr("ID")="cowman" : dr("Name")="bugle"

                'Method 3 does change dt
                'drFilters(1)("ID")="cowman" : drFilters(1)("Name")="bugle"

                output(dt)    'Output final table
        End Sub

        Public Shared Sub output(dt as DataTable)
                for each dr as DataRow in dt.Rows
                        Console.WriteLine(dr("ID") + vbTab + dr("Name"))
                Next
                Console.WriteLine("")
        End Sub

End Class
```

Apologies for the stupid test data :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `drFilters(1)=dr`, you have replaced the `DataRow` reference in the filter collection, which is a separate collection from the row references in the `DataTable` itself.  `dt.Rows` is a list of references to `DataRow` objects, as is `drFilters()`, but changing an entry in one list of references does not in any way affect the other list of references.

```
dt.Rows
0 => dt.Rows(0)
1 => dt.Rows(1)
2 => dt.Rows(2)
3 => dt.Rows(3)
4 => dt.Rows(4)

drFilter()
0 => dt.Rows(0)
1 => dt.Rows(1)
2 => dt.Rows(2)
```

After the call to `drFilters(1)=dr`, the collections look like this

```
dt.Rows
0 => dt.Rows(0)
1 => dt.Rows(1)
2 => dt.Rows(2)
3 => dt.Rows(3)
4 => dt.Rows(4)

drFilter()
0 => dt.Rows(0)
1 => dr
2 => dt.Rows(2)
```

Note that `dt.Rows` is left unchanged.  However, when you retrieve the object `drFilters(1)` and make changes to that, you have a reference directly to `dt.Rows(1)`, so changes to its properties are reflected in the output of `dt`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice answer. I understood how it worked already and I still think I udnerstand it better now. :)